# What are design features of impact type screwdriver bits?

Tags: tools

Modern screwdriver bits, marketed for impact tool use, have "torsion" control, apparently implemented with a necking of the bit.

Does this feature reduce the delivered peak torque?

Practically, does it reduce bit failure?

Comment: They work on the same principle as "torque sticks" but on a smaller scale - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6ccxHCwnQPY disclaimer: I'm on mobile and haven't watched this video to see if it's any good - was the first result, to give you a place to start.

Comment: So then to some degree they reduce torque to the fastener, apparently.  A softer drive?

Comment: To some degree, yes - they will limit peak 'impact torque' if you are using an impact driver, but will have no effect on static 'stall torque', if you were to use those bits with a standard drill/driver.